# ReadRaster returns wrong pixel value

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, c#

I'm trying to read a GeoTIFF with one band which stores a value between 0 and 3 ( 255 is no maks ). I downloaded it from here :
https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/QQHCIK

And if you wanna take a look at it... heres the download link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/104De_YQN1V8tSbj2uhIPO0FfowjnInnX/view?usp=sharing

Unfortunately i have no further informations about the tif files in there and im still a noob.

I need to get the pixel value for a certain geo-coordinate. However, my code somehow returns the wrong pixel value for the given coordinate... it returns 255 when it should return 2.

What am I doing wrong?

```
            GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
            var tif = "C:\\Users\\Lars\\Downloads\\pnv_biome.type_biome00k_c_1km_s0..0cm_2000..2017_v0.1.tif";
            var lat = 51.0;
            var lon = 8.3;
            using (var image = Gdal.Open(tif, Access.GA_ReadOnly)) {

                var bOneBand = image.GetRasterBand(1);
                var width = bOneBand.XSize;
                var height = bOneBand.YSize;
                
                // Geocoordinate ( lat, lon ) to pixel in the tiff ? 
                var geoTransform = new double[6];
                image.GetGeoTransform(geoTransform);
                Gdal.InvGeoTransform(geoTransform, geoTransform);
                
                var bOne = new int[1];
                Gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(geoTransform, lat, lon, out var pixelXF, out var pixelYF);

                var pixelX = (int)Math.Floor(pixelXF);
                var pixelY = (int)Math.Floor(pixelYF);
                
                // Read pixel 
                bOneBand.ReadRaster(pixelX, pixelY, 1, 1, bOne, 1, 1,0,0);
                Console.WriteLine(bOne[0]); // bOne[0] contains wrong data
            }
```

Comment: Is it an 8-bit image, or something more exotic, like a 4-bit or 2-bit?  Please [edit] the question.

Comment: @Vince Excellent question... im still a noob on that topic, where can i see this ? What i just saw is that it also crashes when i insert negative coordinates, which is quite interessting aswell.

Comment: @Vince I downloaded the file from here https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/QQHCIK I cant really find anything usefull about what type of image it is

Comment: Learn to use gdalinfo https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html.